# Using bash like a boss - synergy

Tags: bash

I have a data set that needs altering and I can't justify that I need to use Perl. I'm trying to remove "Full rights" using Bash. However, I need to get rid of not only what is in the parenthesis, but the parenthesis themselves. How do I do this because when I use the sed - it gets rid OF EVERYTHING!

```
7X7AMFull rights (Secondary)99999Full rights (Unknown)AAAMFull rights
(Unknown)AAAMAHKFull rights (Unknown)AAAMNLFull rights (Unknown)
AAMAHFull rights (Unknown)ABBINFull rights (Unknown)ABBPTLLPFull rights
(Primary)ABBYFull rights (Unknown)ABCCFull rights (Primary)ABCCNYFull rights 
(Unknown)ABCJORFull rights (Primary)ABDHFull rights (Unknown)ABERDEENFull rights (Unknown) 
ABINGDFull rights (Secondary)ABNEQUKFull rights (Unknown)ABPFull rights (Unknown)ABPALGEFull rights (Unknown)ABSAAMPFull rights 
(Primary)ABSOLUTFull rights (Secondary)ABSOLUTEFull rights (Support)ABUAUTHFull rights (Primary)ABUDHFull rights (Unknown)ACACIAFull rights   
(Primary)ACACIAMGFull rights (Primary)ACTALBKFull rights (Unknown)ADELGAFull rights (Secondary)ADELPHIFull rights (Primary)ADIGFull rights   
(Unknown)AEGAMFull rights (Unknown)AENEASFull rights (Unknown)AERIONFull rights 
(Primary)AFFILIAT [Sub-accounts] Full rights (Secondary)AGAMEMFull rights (Primary)AGFMFull rights (Secondary)AIGINVERFull rights (Primary)AIMFull rights 
(Support)AKERFull rights (Primary)AKITAASE
```

This is what I get:

```
bash-3.2$
-bash-3.2$
-bash-3.2$ echo "(Primary)ABDHFull" | sed -e 's/\([A-Z,a-z]\)//g'
()
-bash-3.2$
```

What I want to get just a ABDH --- however when I use this, it gets rid of everything and just leaves the parenthesis.

How do I get just ABDH from "(Primary)ABDHFull rights".
The above list ideally should look something like this - synergy, like a boss.

7X7AM
99999
AAAM
AAAMAHK
AAAMNL
AAMAH 
ABBIN
ABBPTLLP
ABBY
ABCC
ABCCNY 
ABCJOR

Comment: `grep -oP '(?<=\))[^ ]*(?=Full)' <<< "string"`

Comment: oh my goodness - three less than signs.

Comment: that is using grep like a BOSS !!!!!

Comment: I think that the P is a flag that uses grep with perl regex.

Comment: You need: `echo "(Primary)ABDHFull" | sed -e 's/([^()]*)//g'`. you are trying to capture ONE and ONLY ONE upper or lower case character or a comma, and replace it with nothing

Comment: Gwillie - you should write that as answer - get some credit.

Comment: `\(...\)` in sed (BRE) is a capturing group, equivalent to `(...)` in Perl. Your statement is therefore equivalent to `s/[A-Z,a-z]//g` and that's why it removes everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As requested) You need:

```
echo "(Primary)ABDHFull" | sed -e 's/([^()]*)//g'.
```

you are trying to capture ONE and ONLY ONE upper or lower case character or a comma, and replace it with nothing